# Como desactivar el boton de envio hasta que se verifique el recaptcha en React

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha

Necesito bloquear el boton del formulario hasta que verfiquen el recaptcha,estoy usando react-google-recaptcha

1.-Estas son mis importaciones mi mi codigo la funcion onChange le puse un console.log Para verificar que si manda la informacion

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/Contact.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function onChange(value) {
    console.log("Captcha value:", value);
  }
```

2.-Este es mi ReCaptcha y mi boton pero la condicion que puse en el disabled no funciona este es el codigo

```
<div className="col">
                <ReCAPTCHA
                  className="recap"
                  sitekey="{siteKey}"
                />
                <button
                  disabled={!onChange}
                  type="submit"
                  class="btn btn-outline-light buttonSubmit"
                >
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={["fas", "paper-plane"]}
                    className="Iconsubmitbutton"
                  />{" "}
                  Enviar
                </button>
              </div>
```

Comment: la función `onChange`  no retorna nada, por eso no funciona en el disabled

Comment: Gracias bro,tienes alguna idea de cómo podría hacerlo?